# Configure WebTestClient to always do something

Tags: java, spring, spring-test, spring-restdocs

I'm trying to setup `WebTestClient` to always document, like we can do with `MockMvc`.

`MockMvcBuilders` can be configured to always do something, like do some Spring Restdocs documentation, like so:

```
MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(context)
      .apply(documentationConfiguration(this.restDocumentation))
      .alwaysDo(document(getClass().getSimpleName() + "_" + this.testName.getMethodName()))
      .build()
```

Would this also be possible for the reactive variant, `WebTestClient`?

```
WebTestClient.bindToApplicationContext(context).configureClient()
                                 .filter(documentationConfiguration(this.restDocumentation))
                                      // alwaysDo?
                                           .build();
```